# Login in Spring security redirects to error Thymeleaf and Java based Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am trying to implement Role based Authentication on my Spring Application. However, I get Redirected to http://localhost:8080/login?error=true even if the credentials are right and hibernate fetches the login credentials without an issue.

Here is my SecurityConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
        "/css/**","/js/**","/image/**","/fonts/**","/webfonts/**","/register","/login","/actuator/**"
};


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()        
        .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/addShipping").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
        .antMatchers("/item/add").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true").defaultSuccessUrl("/",true)
        .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .deleteCookies("remember-me")
            .permitAll()
        .and().rememberMe()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/denied");


  }

@Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
      throws Exception {
      auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
          .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
  }
```

Here is My login Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String login(Model model) { 

    return "login"; 
}
```

My Role Class

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Role {

@Id
@Column(name="role_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name ="role")
private String role;
```

}

User Class

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User implements UserDetails {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name ="user_id")
private Long id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Cart cart;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private List<Order> order;

@NotEmpty(message="username is required")
private  String username;

@NotEmpty(message="password is required")
private  String password;

@NotEmpty(message="password is required")
private  String fullname;

private int enabled;

@NotBlank(message="Pleace Provide your Role")
private String role;


@NotEmpty
@Email 
private String email;

@NotEmpty(message="phone is required")
private  String phone;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable( name="user_role", 
            joinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="role_id")})
private Set<Role> roles;

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = roles
            .stream()
            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());


    return authorities;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
    }


}
```

Login Template

```
                                <div th:if="${param.error != null}" style="color: red;">Incorrect credentials</div>
                                <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
                                    <div class="form-group"><input required="required" type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" /></div>
                                    <div class="form-group"> <input required="required" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" /></div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 text-center">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="" name="remember" id="remember">
                                        <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3"> <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log in</button> </div>
                                </form>
```

[EDIT]

User Service

```
public interface UserService extends UserDetailsService {

    void save(User user);

    User findUserByUsername(String username);

}
```

User Sevice Implementation

```
@Service
public class UserServicelmpl implements UserService {

  private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

  private UserRepository userRepository;

  private RoleRepository roleRepository;



  @Autowired
  public UserServicelmpl(UserRepository userRepository, RoleRepository 
roleRepository, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
  }

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
      throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

    if (user != null) {
      return user;
    }

    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("The user with user name of '" + 
username + "' is not found");
   }

  @Override
  public void save(User user) {

      user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
      user.setEnabled(true);
      String Role = "ROLE_"+ user.getRole();
      Role userRole = roleRepository.findByRole(Role);
      user.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(Arrays.asList(userRole)));
      userRepository.save(user);

  }

  @Override
    public User findUserByUsername(String username) {
      return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    } 
}
```

**[EDIT 2]**
Log

o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authentication failed: password does not match stored value

w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials

org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:93) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:166) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]

Comment: Remove .anyRequest().authenticated() and see whether u r being login successfully. Then place it after roles antMatchers.

Comment: Already tried that with no luck!

Comment: That must be some stupid typo/misconfiguration. We need more info. Add `logging.level.org.springframework.security = DEBUG` to your application properties and include the logs in your question please.

Comment: Oh. I've just noticed you load the roles eagerly, which means that it's loaded *before* the password check happens. So it's also possible that you have invalid credentials stored in the DB. Are you absolutely sure the password is stored in the DB properly encoded?

Comment: I have Updated with logging.level.org.springframework.security = DEBUG added to my application.properties file

Comment: @Selindek you are Right. It appears the password stored and the input does not match.  However to ensure it is not my problem I deleted all my tables and registered a new user with a password "a". Then tried it It showed in the log that the password doesn't match again.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this method:

```
@Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
      throws Exception {
      auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
          .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
  }
```

Spring Boot automatically picks the `UserDetailsService` and `PasswordEncoder` beans. if you override this method it uses a completely different way for creating the AuthenticationManager

Comment: I removed the override and nothing is different... I have added the hibernate log on my second edit

Comment: Does your test user has any role set in the DB? I don't remember clearly, but I think that somewhere in the Spring Security there is an assertion that there must be at least one authentication for a user.

Comment: I added role_id and role in Role Table  myself in the DB